# Changing Fragments. Why does it not work

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I got this Code for changing Fragments with a Navigation drawer in Android Java. Simply followed official Googles Dev Posts and other pages, but it still doesn't work. Just the Header of the page changes but not the layout. Tell me please why, i wouldn't be asking if i havent tried a lot and read other Posts.

So here's my Code:
In MainActivity Java file

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        Fragment f = null;
        Class fClass = null;
        // Tasklist
        if (id == R.id.nav_drawer_main_tasklist) {
            fClass = TaskList.class;
        }
    try{
            f=(Fragment) fClass.newInstance();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_main,f).commit();

        item.setChecked(true);
        setTitle(item.getTitle());
        // Drawer
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout_main);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START

);
```

in TaskList Java

```
public class TaskList extends Fragment {

View view;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_tasklist, container, false);
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

}
```

in tasklists XML file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="***">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_main_createtask"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:onClick="fab_main_createtask_onClick"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">



    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_tasklist, container, false);
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

}
```

the above is wrong, return the inflated layout and remove nullable.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_tasklist, container, false);
    return view;

}
```

Comment: your triggered the default onCreateView which results in nothing

Comment: view cannot be cannot null, so that annotation is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `return` your own `fragment` view. Update your `TaskList` fragment as below:

```
public class TaskList extends Fragment {

    View view;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_tasklist, container, false);
       return view ;  
   }
}
```

Comment: when you guys answer do you check if the same answer is already there, just curious, cause i already posted the answer.

Comment: also telling the that method it can be nullable is incorrect, a fragment cannot be null.